# Correct express promises

Tags: javascript, express, promise

I have 2 functions in customer module, both are promises:

1. Is to parse the http body into a customerData object.
2. Pass the customerData into saveCustomer to save it into the db.

Inside my route I do this:

```
    customers.parse(body).then(function (customerData){        
        return customerData;
    }).then(function (merchantData){
        customers.saveCustomer(customerData).then(function (merchant) {
            res.success(merchant);
        })
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.error(err);
    });
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yah, I just want to know, am I doing it right? because I am with promises, so I am not sure how to use it correctly.

Comment: `customers.saveCustomer(customerData)` - looks wrong, as customerData will be undefined most likely ... other than that, the .then on the same line can be outside that function, chained like you did the first two .then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be simplified as below:

```
customers.parse(body)
  .then(function (customerData){
    return customers.saveCustomer(customerData)
  }).then(function (merchant) {
    res.success(merchant);
  }, function (err) {
    res.error(err);
  });
```

Explanation:

- the first `then` in your code is redundant.
- it would be good idea to chain `customers.saveCustomer` to first promise, insead of creating seperate chain.
- the catch would be missing the `customers.saveCustomer` error case because you were not returning that promise.

Comment: You could even do `.then(customers.saveCustomer.bind(customers))`.